# Cursor Index Out Of Bounds when default value assigned

Tags: android, sqlite

I just assigned default value when table created but I got error when I want to get assigned value :

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Nooo (N_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0, yes TEXT DEFAULT '1');");

SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor myCursor = DB.rawQuery("SELECT yes FROM Nooo",null);
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    String aa=myCursor.getString(0);
```

and on above line error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743833/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-exception).
Probably you have error because you have not insert any data into table.

Comment: is it not possible to get default value from table ?

Comment: Default value assign to table column if you insert row item in to table, but without any value defined to current column.
So to get default value from column you need to insert at least one row or here is the answer you looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591077/sql-server-get-default-value-of-a-column

Answer (score 0):

1) The use of default value is to **fill/initialize** that element of the table with some default values if no value is passed for that element. But this will come into picture only if you insert something.

2) No there are no api to get the default value. 
It's your db so you know the default value so why you need any api for that?